# Emails going to spam even though DKIM and SPF records set up and rDNS too in EC2. I am usinf postfix and dovecot

Tags: amazon-web-services, postfix, dovecot, spam, roundcube

I have set up my own email server in AWS using postfix and dovecot. I have also set up DKIP and SPF and DMARC records. Now the problem is when i send an email from admin@example.com, its not flagged as spam in gmail. Infact, its automatically marked as important. Same with forum@example.com. But, when I am sending it from any other address like contact@example.com, its being flagged as spam. I'm totally confused as to why this is happening. I use roundcube webmail.

EDIT: i created a new gmail test account and in that test account,all the emails from my domain are going to spam regardless of forum@example.com, contact@example.com etc.

Here is my domain: arcadesite.io

Comment: No because I have already added DKIM SPF and DMARC records. Its an AWS ellastic IP so it should not have a "low" reputation

Comment: Every AWS IP has a low reputation.

Comment: How can I increase reputation of the IP ?because I have configured DKIM and SPF records.....so cannot do anything more I guess.Also, rDNS is configured on that ellasic IP

Comment: Best post your domain name / IP so people can check reputation and such for you. I have my web server hosted on EC2 but I use FastMail for email, because I don't want to have to spend the time managing and maintaining it.

Comment: Yes. Edited the post with my domain name

Comment: i would suggest to setup an vps outsite of aqs for 2eur/m as relay and dont have the pain for paying attention to any Reputation, for fast setup take a Look for mailcow, it needs 4gb RAM but its every bit worth

Comment: So will it solve my problem? And can i install mailcow alongside wordpress etc on a diff folder and using apache vhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern spam filters use different signals to classify an email. How exactly it is done differs by implementation, but in general the sender only has indirect control over many of those. Just because an email system is cleanly implemented, does not mean it won't be sending spam; using that as the only signal would defeat the purpose.

- SPF and DKIM ensure that the email was emitted by the owning system, preventing spammers from abusing random addresses.
- A valid rDNS suggests that you actually have some control over the IP you're sending from.
- [Then there are blacklists](https://whatismyipaddress.com/blacklist-check), which some systems, e.g. [SpamAssassin](https://spamassassin.apache.org/), query to identify known bad senders.
- Large email services often keep statistics on a sender through their own users feedback. If enough people hit the "spam button" on the first messages of a campaign, it's likely to end up in the spam folder for everyone else.
- Some mail providers share IP reputation data with [third party services](https://www.senderscore.org), which in return provide a more detailed analysis of a sender.
- Content analysis also plays a role. If an individual message contains questionable content (think Viagra), it may get classified as spam despite originating from a reputable sender.
- Sending large amounts of mail to non-existing addresses, i.e. using dirty lists, is another hallmark of spammers and has a negative impact on reputation, too.

In a nutshell, being trusted by the major providers like GMail, Yahoo or MSN takes time and consistent sending of quality content that recipients actually want, and won't get flagged by users or content analysis.

If you use an address from a VPS hoster, where IPs are a dime a dozen and change ownership often, you'll start out with rather low trust. Use reputation and blacklist checks to ensure the IP doesn't already have a bad history. If it does, contact the list maintainers where possible, and explain that the IP is under new ownership. Most will allow a fresh start.

If you send bulk email, you can also participate in [feedback loops](https://www.drh.net/blog/email-feedback-loops-what-are-they-how-to-use-them) to remove people who classify your messages as spam from your list, and as such avoid the associated penalties in the future.

Comment: besides all said above, you have issue with DMARC record (2 DMARC records) which need to fixed.  Check here ->  https://easydmarc.com/tools/dmarc/arcadesite.io  https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#TXT/_dmarc.arcadesite.io